# How to release resources when tearing down an Akka graph?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have this code:

```
def makeFlow()(implicit timeout: Timeout): Flow[Any, Any, NotUsed] = {
  val ref: ActorRef = startActor()
  Flow[Any].mapAsync(42)(ref.ask)
}
```

This is going to leak actors. Every time I materialise a graph containing this flow, an actor will be created. When the graph is torn down, this actor won't be destroyed.

I know [how to stop an actor](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-stop-akka-actors-in-scala-gracefulstop-poisonpill). How do I arrange for that to happen when the graph is stopped?

Comment: Do the Actors and the Akka Stream share the ActorSystem?

Comment: @mdm Yes, they share the same ActorSystem.

Comment: Can you adjust the return type to `(Flow[Any, Any, NotUsed], ActorRef)`?  Then you can use whatever shutdown approach (poisonpill, etc.) is appropriate to your use case after materialization.

Comment: @LeviRamsey I could, but I'm hoping there's some way I can encapsulate it all within this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that youre at the Flow-level, so when this is used there is nothing indicating when would be the correct time for the actor to be destroyed.
You could let the actor schedule a poison pill for himself after some idle time, but that looks like ugly design.
Therefore, what Levi Ramsey proposes looks like your cleanest option. Another one would be to pass an indicator object for the Graph state and if that indicates that currently the last element flows through it, a poison pill can be sent after asking.